# Find an instance of a Kaprekar number

Tags: equation-solving, functions

Here are two instances of an Kaprekar number

$\text{9${}^{\wedge}
   $2 = 81 $\&$  8+1=9}$

$\text{8${}^{\wedge}
   $3 = 512 $\&$ 5+1+2=8}$

There are certainly more with a higher exponent , perhaps an infinite number of them.

However with the line of code below

```
FindInstance[ x^y == z  && x > 1 && y > 1  && Total[IntegerDigits[z]] == x, {x, y, z}, Integers, 1]
```

MMA V11.3 does not return a single instance. Is there anything wrong in this  code or is it a limitation of the `FindInstance` function ?

Comment: Just curious: you write the formulas in LaTeX, which is a way to typeset traditional mathematical notation on a computer, but you make special effort to make it look like computer code regardless. Why?

Comment: 12.0 gives you a reason: "The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist." If you reformulate the problem to avoid `Total` and `IntegerDigits`, then it works, but then we need to hard-code the number of digits.

Comment: Your definition of a Kaprekar number does not agree with the definition given in [`MathWorld`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KaprekarNumber.html) or [`OEIS A006886`](https://oeis.org/A006886). For those definitions, `8` is not a Kaprekar number. The OEIS gives the Mathematica code written by T. D. Noe which generates 1035 Kaprekar numbers.

Comment: According  to [mrob](http://mrob.com/pub/seq/kaprekar.html#table_4)  8 is an order-3 Kaprekar number and  9 an order-2 (normal) one. The contents of your links don't contradict the one I point to but they are not as exhaustive. True I overlooked in my code to divide `z` into `y` equal pieces before adding them up.But I know now from the answer received that `FindInstance` is not up to the task even with V12.0 (version I don't have) which at first not evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute-force search will be much better here than `FindInstance`.

```
In[16]:= First@Last@Reap@Do[
    If[Total@IntegerDigits[x^y] == x, Sow[{x, y}]],
    {x, 2, 20}, {y, 2, 10}
    ]

Out[16]= {{7, 4}, {8, 3}, {9, 2}, {17, 3}, {18, 3}, {18, 6}, {18, 7}}
```